# Huggingface model.generate iterative 1 token (batch_size = 1)

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model

I'm trying to understand the difference between using model.generate(input_id, attention_mask, max_new_tokens=200, min_length=15), and

```
while count < 200:
output = model.generate(input_id, attention_mask, max_new_tokens=1, min_length=0)
input_id = output
count +=1
```

The stopping criteria can be made the same, including checking for EOS token_id. I understand that the first method would outperform as batch_size > 1, but for batch_size = 1, why is method 2 so much more slower than method 1? I can pass use_cache=True, but that did not help